# Updating other React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Navbar that has buttons that change the language of the website. Instead of using different htmls, I'm just replacing the text with what I have in a database. However, doing anything in a component only updates that component and I need a way to update every other one

I haven't tried anything useful yet, since there's a complicated layout for usual solutions.

App.js

```
function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <div className="container" id="main">
        <Navbar />
       <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
         <Route path="/gallery" component={Gallery}></Route>
       </Switch>
       </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My Navbar is outside of Switch that contains all the different pages I need to update.

All I need to do is to somehow pass an update request to every other component. Would be nice if it'd happen without reloading the page, though that would somewhat work.

Comment: Maybe put the language in the [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention using Redux, so I assuming you are just using React state. Keep the language in the state of the top-level component, and pass the language to the components that need it. Give Switch a call-back function that changes the top-level state when the language is changed.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow, let you know how it's going! Thanks for the help